# Remove file from dependency jar using maven

Tags: maven-2

I am trying to remove a file from a dependency jar that I am including in my war file in maven. I am deploying the war to JBoss 5.1 and the jar in question contains a persistence.xml file that I don't want.

Here's what is going on:

```
my-webapp.war
|
`-- WEB-INF
    |
    `-- lib
        |
        `-- dependency.jar
            |
            `-- META-INF
                |
                `-- persistence.xml
```

When I am building my war, I want to remove persistence.xml Any one have any idea if this can be done easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not available out of the box AFAIK, you'll have to use the Maven AntRun plugin after `package` to do a few dirty things:

- unzip the war in a temp directory
- unzip the dependency in another temp directory
- delete the file from the dependency
- zip the temp directory of the dependency back into a jar
- move the dependency back in the temp directory of the war
- zip the temp directory of the webapp back into a war
- delete the temp directory of the dependency
- delete the temp directory of the webapp

#### The following resources might help

- [ant task to remove files from a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521231/ant-task-to-remove-files-from-a-jar)
- [RE: Removing a file from .jar file](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/ant-user/200605.mbox/%3C20060505182830.72097.qmail@web30908.mail.mud.yahoo.com%3E)

---

Now, if the problem is that JBoss is deploying the persistence unit defined in the `persistence.xml` (and you don't want that), there might be a better solution.  It seems that you can declare files to ignore in a `jboss-ignore.txt` file, for example:

```
WEB-INF/lib/dependency.jar/META-INF/persistence.xml
```

The feature is there, but I've never used it.

#### See

- [Excluding persistence.xml from deployment](http://community.jboss.org/message/539967)
- [JBoss5 custom metadata files](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBoss5custommetadatafiles)

Answer (score 17):

You can achieve this with the [TrueZIP Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/truezip/truezip-maven-plugin/).

This should work for your use case:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>truezip-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>remove-a-file-in-sub-archive</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>remove</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <fileset>
                    <directory>target/my-webapp.war/WEB-INF/lib/dependency.jar/META-INF</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>persistence.xml</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileset>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Also see [the examples](https://github.com/mojohaus/truezip/tree/master/truezip-maven-plugin/src/it).

Comment: This is amazing! This should be the accepted answer, as the truezip plugin takes all the manual work out of your hands.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you would have to use the maven shade plugin (see link below)

Either build an Über-jar that includes your dependency minus the persistence-xml or just transform the dependency into something new that does not have the persistence.xml.

This should be the way to go:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html

Sean

Comment: I thought about that but how would you plug this in the build? How would you tell the maven war plugin to pick the überjar instead of the "real" dependency.

Comment: add a classifier to the dependency of the war plugin. add a deploy lifecycle that deploys the uberjar to your build. Actually, a local install will probably do. Take a look at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html

Sean