# ant : jar and zipfileset - copy files from one JAR into another

Tags: java, ant, build, jar, zip

I am currently doing this:

```
<jar update="yes"
     jarfile="${pwd}/dist/${release}_installer.jar">
   <zipfileset src="${pwd}/dist/app.jar" includes="com/izforge/izpack/panels/**"/>
   <zipfileset src="${pwd}/dist/app.jar" includes="com/xyz/img/logo.png"/>
</jar>
```

My existing installer JAR gets updated to include the files as needed, extracted from the app JAR.

So far, so good.

However, I want to modify the behaviour such that the path of the image file is different than what is being copied from:

Currently:

```
com/izforge/izpack/panels/MyIzPanel.class
com/xyz/img/logo.png
```

What I want:

```
com/izforge/izpack/panels/MyIzPanel.class
blah/img/logo.png
```

So I need to copy the files, but use [`<zipfileset>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/zipfileset.html) and [`<jar>`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/jar.html) in such a way that I can modify the directory structure.

Is there a way to do this, apart from unzipping the entire contents copying file and then zipping it back up again?

---

EDIT:

Link to earlier related question: [ant task to remove files from a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521231/ant-task-to-remove-files-from-a-jar)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `fullpath` attribute:

```
<zipfileset src="${pwd}/dist/app.jar"
    includes="com/xyz/img/logo.png" fullpath="blah/img/logo.img"/>
```

If you need to copy several files you may want to have a look at the `prefix` attribute, e.g.:

```
<zipfileset src="${pwd}/dist/app.jar"
    includes="**/*.png" prefix="blah/img"/>
```

Comment: I did trry prefix, h/w I get `blah/img/com/xyz/img/logo.png` instead of `blah/img/logo.png`, which is what I want.

Comment: Yup, `fullpath` does work for a single file, however I have got multiple `.png` files which I want to map... I have been looking at the `mapper` ( http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/mapper.html ) ant types, but haven't managed to get them working...

Comment: For more than one file, if `prefix` does not suit your needs, then yes, you will need to use mappers.

Answer (score 2):

In order to modify the directory structure within the archive on the fly you can use the  task in combination with `<mappedresources`>, eg:

```
<jar file="target.jar" update="true">
  <mappedresources>
    <zipfileset src="source.jar">
      <include name="com/xyz/img/*.png"/>
    </zipfileset>
    <mapper type="glob" from="com/xyz/img/*.png" to="bla/img/*.png" />
  </mappedresources>
</jar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into [zipgroupfileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6292559/293933).