# How can I use a zipfileset src attribute without having to specify it manually for all my jars?

Tags: ant, jarjar

I currently have this:

```
<jarjar destfile="a.jar" manifest="Manifest.mf">
  <zipfileset src="first.jar"/>
  <zipfileset src="second.jar"/>
</jarjar>
```

The problem is I have to manually specify each jar, because I need the src parameter to be taken in consideration. I would want something like this:

```
<zipfileset>
   <include name="*.jar"/>
<zipfileset>
```

And have their contents extracted and included in my resulting archive. Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe you could merge the jars first with:

```
<zip destfile="out.jar">
  <zipgroupfileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar"/>
</zip>
```

and specify the merged jar in the zipfileset.

[zipgroupfileset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html)

> ```
> A <zipgroupfileset> allows for multiple zip files to be merged into
> ```
>
> the archive. Each file found in this
>   fileset is added to the archive the
>   same way that zipfileset src files are
>   added.
>
> ```
> <zipgroupfileset> is a fileset and supports all of its attributes and
> ```
>
> nested elements.

Answer (score 5):

According to comments on the [jarjar wiki](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/wiki/GettingStarted), you can use this in your jarjar:

```
<zipgroupfileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar" />
```

I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<jar destfile="./dist/Ohmyfish.jar" basedir="./bin">
    <manifest>
        <attribute name="Created-By" value="Bruce Yang" />
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="org.bruce.ohmyfish.entry.Main" />
    </manifest>
    <zipgroupfileset dir="./libs" includes="**/*.jar" />
</jar>
```